# MS Access - Query too complex (possibly long) - How to fix or shorten?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access, I'm using switch to update a column based on the ID of each row. This SQL should be working; however Access hits back with a "Expression too complex in query expression". If this is t he case, is there any way to work around or possibly shorten this SQL to make it work?

*note -1 means the buyer name's first initial comes before M in the alphabet, 0 means it is M, and 1 means it comes after M. This is just a test for another purpose.

```
Update AmazonCustomers SET Category = Switch(ID =1, -1, ID =2, 0, ID =3, -1, ID =4, -1, ID =5, -1, ID =6, -1, ID =7, 1, ID =8, -1, ID =9, -1, ID =10, -1, ID =11, -1, ID =12, 1, ID =13, 0, ID =14, -1, ID =15, -1, ID =16, -1, ID =17, 1, ID =18, -1, ID =19, 0, ID =20, 1, ID =21, -1, ID =22, -1, ID =23, -1, ID =24, -1, ID =25, -1, ID =26, -1, ID =27, -1, ID =28, -1, ID =29, 1, ID =30, 1, ID =31, 1, ID =32, -1, ID =33, -1, ID =34, 1, ID =35, -1, ID =36, 1, ID =37, -1, ID =38, -1, ID =39, -1, ID =40, 0, ID =41, 0, ID =42, 1, ID =43, -1, ID =44, -1, ID =45, -1, ID =46, 1, ID =47, -1, ID =48, 1, ID =49, -1, ID =50, 0, ID =51, -1, ID =52, 1, ID =53, -1, ID =54, -1, ID =55, 1, ID =56, 1, ID =57, 1, ID =58, -1, ID =59, 1, ID =60, -1, ID =61, -1, ID =62, 1, ID =63, -1, ID =64, -1, ID =65, -1, ID =66, 1, ID =67, -1, ID =68, 1, ID =69, 1, ID =70, -1, ID =71, 1, ID =72, -1, ID =73, -1, ID =74, -1, ID =75, -1, ID =76, 0, ID =77, 1, ID =78, 0, ID =79, 1, ID =80, -1, ID =81, -1, ID =82, 1, ID =83, -1, ID =84, 0, ID =85, -1, ID =86, 1, ID =87, -1, ID =88, -1, ID =89, -1, ID =90, -1, ID =91, -1, ID =92, 0, ID =93, -1, ID =94, -1, ID =95, -1, ID =96, -1, ID =97, -1, ID =98, -1, ID =99, 1, ID =100, -1, ID =101, 1, ID =102, 1, ID =103, -1, ID =104, 1, ID =105, -1, ID =106, 1, ID =107, -1, ID =108, 1, ID =109, 1, ID =110, 0, ID =111, -1, ID =112, -1, ID =113, 1, ID =114, 0, ID =115, -1, ID =116, -1, ID =117, 1, ID =118, 0, ID =119, 0, ID =120, -1, ID =121, 0, ID =122, 0, ID =123, 0, ID =124, -1, ID =125, 1, ID =126, -1, ID =127, 1, ID =128, -1, ID =129, -1, ID =130, -1, ID =131, -1, ID =132, -1, ID =133, -1, ID =134, 1, ID =135, -1, ID =136, -1, ID =137, -1, ID =138, -1, ID =139, -1, ID =140, -1, ID =141, -1, ID =142, -1, ID =143, 0, ID =144, -1, ID =145, -1, ID =146, -1, ID =147, 1, ID =148, -1, ID =149, 1, ID =150, -1, ID =151, 1, ID =152, -1, ID =153, 0, ID =154, -1, ID =155, -1, ID =156, -1, ID =157, -1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say when the value should be 1, 0 or -1 in brief if possible?

Comment: Okay, as per your update, there is no relation between category and id.

Comment: Since this is apparently a one-time deal where you're arbitrarily setting values based on constants, I'd say dump this into Excel and generate 157 separate `update` statements.

Comment: This is a join -- you just need the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to run this as separate UPDATE statements?
If so, you could have queries like:

```
UPDATE AmazonCustomers 
SET Category = -1
WHERE ID IN (1, 3, 4, ...);

UPDATE AmazonCustomers 
SET Category = 0
WHERE ID IN (2, 13, 19, ...);

UPDATE AmazonCustomers 
SET Category = 1
WHERE ID IN (7, 17, 20, ...);
```

Add in the numbers manually inside the IN statements that match your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with a single join.

Note -- if you are doing this a lot put the values in a real table and join to that.

```
Update AmazonCustomers (Category)
      SELECT T.V
      FROM AmazonCustomers 
      JOIN (
      SELECT 1, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 4, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 5, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 6, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 7, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 8, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 9, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 10, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 11, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 12, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 13, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 14, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 15, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 16, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 17, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 18, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 19, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 20, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 21, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 22, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 23, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 24, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 25, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 26, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 27, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 28, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 29, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 30, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 31, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 32, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 33, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 34, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 35, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 36, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 37, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 38, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 39, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 40, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 41, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 42, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 43, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 44, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 45, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 46, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 47, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 48, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 49, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 50, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 51, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 52, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 53, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 54, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 55, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 56, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 57, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 58, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 59, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 60, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 61, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 62, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 63, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 64, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 65, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 66, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 67, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 68, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 69, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 70, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 71, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 72, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 73, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 74, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 75, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 76, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 77, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 78, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 79, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 80, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 81, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 82, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 83, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 84, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 85, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 86, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 87, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 88, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 89, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 90, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 91, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 92, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 93, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 94, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 95, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 96, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 97, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 98, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 99, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 101, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 102, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 103, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 104, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 105, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 106, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 107, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 108, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 109, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 110, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 111, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 112, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 113, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 114, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 115, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 116, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 117, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 118, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 119, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 120, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 121, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 122, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 123, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 124, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 125, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 126, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 127, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 128, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 129, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 130, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 131, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 132, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 133, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 134, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 135, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 136, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 137, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 138, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 139, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 140, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 141, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 142, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 143, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 144, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 145, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 146, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 147, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 148, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 149, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 150, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 151, 1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 152, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 153, 0
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 154, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 155, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 156, -1
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 157, -1
      ) AS T(ID,V) ON T.ID = AmazonCustomers.ID
```